# export + import object vs context

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to search for an answer, but I didn't found one. Maybe I don't know the keywords.

In react, in order to give a component access to a certain value anywhere in your app, we usually use `createContext` + `Provider` + `useContext`.

I've read too that we can skip the `Provider` step, passing the `createContext` a value.

My questions are:

1. If we skip the `Provider` step like mentioned above, we couldn't change the value of the context, right?
2. In the case that I want a value that would NEVER change to be accessible by all components, couldn't I just make a file and export the value, making the value importable by the components, without using React Context/Props? If so, is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use *context* if the data you want to use is statically and globally (*like environment variable*).

Use context if:

- Data is only available in several component scopes.
- or Distributed data can be changed at any time, so all of these data consumer must know if the data has been changed (*reactive*).

For example like the value of the `theme`, it can be `dark` or `light`. The user can change the page to `light` or `dark` whenever he wants. In this case the *context* is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd point won't solve the state change issue.
So, even after the update, your particular variable's value will remain the same, thus, won't make any difference.